# Where to search for the variable declared in magento core blocks?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, magento-community

Hi am just exploring magento files and trying to understand the code.
I came across the below code. This is piece of code from a file in block folder:

```
$pid = $this->getPid();
if ($products[$pid]->getData('list_swatch_attr_values')) { 
    // check to see if product is using configurable swatches.
    // i.e. that is has values in list_swatch_attr_values array.
    $helper->attachGallerySetToCollection($products, $collection->getStoreId());
}
```

I understand a little logic here. But my doubt is where should I look for  `list_swatch_attr_values` whether in other block files or files in model or helper folder. Help me please.

Also there seems to be many methods in magento core files. Is everything user defined or is there predefined methods in PHP of magento core files?

Comment: Which magento version?

Comment: am using magento1.9.2.4. This coding is from an extension `https://github.com/wigman/AjaxSwatches` .  I dont know where to search for the variable `list_swatch_attr_values`.